# Pandas Merges and Suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am writing a Pandas code generator based on an in-house DSL, and am running into a challenge around merges and suffixes.  In SQL, accessing the columns from the result of a `JOIN` is very easy because columns from the `JOIN`'s intermediate result are simply referenced via their alias.  For example:

```
-- dataset_join_node(out, [a, b])
SELECT r1_1.amount AS "sales_vt", r1_2.amount AS "sales_ny", r1_1.amount + r1_2.amount AS "sales_total"
FROM
(
    -- leaf_node(a, fact_sales)
    SELECT ... AS amount
    FROM ...
) AS r1_1
CROSS JOIN
(
    -- leaf_node(b, fact_sales)
    SELECT ... AS amount
    FROM ...
) AS r1_2
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be so easy in Pandas due to column conflicts.  It seems I need to use the `suffixes` keyword and keep track of the resulting column names after the merges are performed and take into account any potential column name conflicts.  For example, my DSL query (not shown) that emitted the SQL displayed above would generate analogous Pandas code like this:

```
...
out_dataset_join_node = (
    a_leaf_node_fact_sales
    .merge(b_leaf_node_fact_sales, how="outer", left_on=["__x"], right_on=["__x"], suffixes=("__1", "__2"))
)

out_dataset_join_node["sales_vt"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount__1"]
out_dataset_join_node["sales_ny"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount__2"]
out_dataset_join_node["sales_total"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount__1"] + out_dataset_join_node["amount__2"]
out_dataset_join_node = out_dataset_join_node[["sales_vt", "sales_ny", "sales_total"]]
...
```

Pandas does not seem to provide an "intermediate" data frame where I could access the columns with an alias, as was done in the SQL above.  In this example, the `amount` column was in both data frames being merged, so the suffixes came into play, and I needed to know that `sales_vt` was from the resulting `amount__1` column, and `sales_ny` was from the resulting `amount__2` column.

If we add a third data frame to the mix, the SQL approach is still straightforward due to the alias prefix of the similarly named `amount` columns:

```
-- dataset_join_node(out, [a, b, c])
SELECT r1_1.amount AS "sales_vt", r1_2.amount AS "sales_ny", r1_3.amount AS "sales_mi",
       r1_1.amount + r1_2.amount + r1_3.amount AS "sales_total"
FROM
(
    -- leaf_node(a, fact_sales)
    SELECT ... AS amount
    FROM ...
) AS r1_1
CROSS JOIN
(
    -- leaf_node(b, fact_sales)
    SELECT ... AS amount
    FROM ...
) AS r1_2
CROSS JOIN
(
    -- leaf_node(c, fact_sales)
    SELECT ... AS amount
    FROM ...
) AS r1_3
```

But the Pandas gets a bit trickier since the last `amount` column does *not* conflict with any previous columns, so it ends up in the resulting data frame as just `amount` (unlike the two previous `amount` columns, which conflict and get renamed to `amount__1` and `amount__2`).

```
out_dataset_join_node = (
    a_leaf_node_fact_sales
    .merge(b_leaf_node_fact_sales, how="outer", left_on=["__x"], right_on=["__x"], suffixes=("__1", "__2"))
    .merge(c_leaf_node_fact_sales, how="outer", left_on=["__x"], right_on=["__x"], suffixes=("__3", "__4"))
)

out_dataset_join_node["sales_vt"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount__1"]
out_dataset_join_node["sales_ny"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount__2"]
out_dataset_join_node["sales_mi"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount"]
out_dataset_join_node["sales_total"] = out_dataset_join_node["amount__1"] + out_dataset_join_node["amount__2"] + out_dataset_join_node["amount"]
out_dataset_join_node = out_dataset_join_node[["sales_vt", "sales_ny", "sales_mi", "sales_total"]]
```

I guess the emitted `suffixes=("__3", "__4")` in the second `.merge()` is unnecessary, but my code generator is not that smart yet.  :-)

My question is, does Pandas have another / better way to accomplish the analogous SQL `JOIN`, possibly (hopefully) with a way to reference columns via an *alias* similar to how SQL lets you access columns via an alias and *then* rename them to whatever you want?

Or is the Pandas `.merge()` and `suffixes` keyword the only tools at my disposal, and my code generator therefore needs to keep track of possible column conflicts and emit code as described above?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Hi... this problem would be easier visualized if  you had some sample data and dataframe structure.

Comment: If you are trying to join on one column to get one column in return.  Let's look at using `map`, however if you're 'joining' on muliple keys or expecting multiple columns in return, then you need to stick with join or merge.

Comment: @ScottBoston yes, potentially joining on multiple keys and expecting to get multiple columns back.